# build_runner: This requires the language feature to be enabled

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

When I use build_runner for **freezed**, **json_serializable**, **auto_route** and using new dart language features like **super-parameters** or **enhanced-enums** at the same files I always get code generation error:

```
*_page.dart:11:11: This requires the 'enhanced-enums' language feature to be enabled.
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use **build.yaml** file inside root project folder to enable language features:

```yaml
 <project_root>
        │
        ├── pubspec.yaml
        │
        └── build.yaml    <----
```

**build.yaml**

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      json_serializable|json_serializable:
        options:
          super-parameters: true
          enhanced-enums: true
      freezed|freezed:
        options:
          super-parameters: true
          enhanced-enums: true
      auto_route|auto_route:
        options:
          super-parameters: true
          enhanced-enums: true
```